# How to resolve Indy DoMaxConnectionsExceeded

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I have created a webserver using Delphi2007 and Indy10.

The server runs fine initially, but after time (usually between 8 and 48 hours) the **DoMaxConnectionsExceeded** method begins to fire; and my web server no longer works properly.  Currently I have **MaxConnections** set to 500.  I have experimented in the past with changing this setting.  And it does seem the larger the value the longer the web server will live.  So it makes me think connections are not being released.

1. Am I doing something wrong in my instantiation?  Why are connections not being released?
2. Is there a way to get a list of all connections (by doing this I can check ip addresses and see if it might be DOS attack).  Also a way to get the url they are trying to hit?
3. I have also experimented with the **KeepAlive** property with no change.
4. Should I set **MaxConnections** to 0?

Source Code for instantiating the TIdHTTPServer:

```
IdHTTPServer1 := TIdHTTPServer.Create;
IdHTTPServer1.MaxConnections := 500;
IdHTTPServer1.AutoStartSession := True;
IdHTTPServer1.KeepAlive := FGlobalKeepAlive;
IdHTTPServer1.SessionState := True;
IdHTTPServer1.OnCommandGet := IdHTTPServer1CommandGet;
IdHTTPServer1.onexception := IdHttpServerexception;
IdHTTPServer1.onlistenexception := IdHttpServerlistenexception;
idHttpServer1.ParseParams := True;
idHttpServer1.OnQuerySSLPort := QuerySSLPort;
idHttpServer1.IOHandler := ServerIOHandler;
idHttpServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 80;
idHttpServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 443;
IdHTTPServer1.Active := True;
```

**Update** - want to add I suspect it might be related to SSL.  I have similar Indy based web servers that don't need SSL.  While they do periodically fail, they don't fail nearly as often.  But with these I am not logging **DoMaxConnectionsExceeded**.  I will add tracking of this event to see if and when they do fail it is because maxconnections is exceeded.

Comment: did you check the connection status with a tool like TCPView or netstat? Maybe it is related to keep-alive, so that clients create a new connection per new request.

Comment: I did do a netstat.  Don't think I saw close to 500 entries.  Next time it enters that state I will do another one and count them.

Comment: What is the value of FGlobalKeepAlive?

Comment: Do the clients use keep-alive? (The server property does not enforce the persistent connections, it depends on the client HTTP protocol version and "Connection" request header)

Comment: @Leonardo Herrera: FGlobalKeepAlive is a boolean that I control.  Again, as explained in the post, I have tried both True and False.  Does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: @mjn - How can I tell?  It can be anyone in the world using any sort of device/browser to view the page.

Comment: Update - I suspect it might have something to do with SSL.  I have another Indy based web server which doesn't employ SSL and it doesn't have nearly the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was wrong.  While I had set KeepAlive to false on the idHTTPServer component, in another area I was manually setting it on the ResponseInfo:

```
  Aresponseinfo.Connection:='keep-alive';
```